# Angular Get Selected Value From Checkbox

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I can't seem to get the selected item from an input checkbox.

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat='shoe in shoebox'>
    <input type='checkbox' ng-model='shoe.selected' id='shoe-{{shoe.name}}'>
    <label for='shoe-{{shoe.name}}'>{{shoe.name}}</label>
  </li>
  <button ng-click='whatIsChecked(shoe.selected)'>Apply</button>
</ul>
```

Then in my controller:

```
$scope.whatIsChecked = function(selectedThing) {
  console.log(selectedThing);
};
```

The above returns `undefined`.

The list items are displayed correctly, but the `shoe.name` or checked item doesn't seem to be stored by the `ng-model`.

Comment: Is the data in **shoebox** updates when you change it?

Comment: I wouldn't be changing the data in shoebox. Currently it is a collection of different shoes that prints out correctly. When I select the associated checkbox, I would like that item to be stored on the model. Hope that answers your question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the variable `shoe` is only valid in `ng-repeat` block.

If you want to got what is selected, you should try `filter`.

**UPD:**
Since you don't have the selected property, you should keep the selected items somewhere else by firing the `ng-click` event.

refer below code snippet.

```js
angular.module("app", [])
  .controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
  
    $scope.checkedShoes = [];
    
    $scope.shoebox = [{
        name: 'shoe1'
      },
      {
        name: 'shoe2'
      },
      {
        name: 'shoe3'
      },
      {
        name: 'shoe4'
      }
    ];
    
    $scope.save = function(e, shoe) {
      if (e.target.checked) {
        $scope.checkedShoes.push(shoe);
      } else {
        var index = $scope.checkedShoes.indexOf(shoe);
        if( index > -1) {
          $scope.checkedShoes.splice(index, 1);
        }
      }
      
    };
    
    $scope.whatIsChecked = function() {
      //var selected = $scope.shoebox.filter(function(item) {
      //  return item.selected === true;
      //});
      
      console.log($scope.checkedShoes);
    }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" , ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat='shoe in shoebox'>
      <input type='checkbox' ng-click="save($event, shoe)" id='shoe-{{shoe.name}}'>
      <label for='shoe-{{shoe.name}}'>{{shoe.name}}</label>
    </li>
    <button ng-click='whatIsChecked()'>Apply</button>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I can run your snippet and it works great, however - when I try - I'm getting an empty array `[]` returned from `console.log(selected)` . I think its because I'm not explicitly setting each shoe to false like you did in your example. Could this be modified to not need a `selected` property in each shoe object?

Comment: @bruh so you mean not to save the selected info in your `shoebox`?

Comment: I used `shoe.selected` as an example name for ng-model. I don't actually have a `selected` property in each shoe object (like you have in your example). *I believe* this is why I'm getting an empty array returned when I try to `console.log(selected)`

Comment: @bruh Got it. wait a moment.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I'm getting the error below (Angular 1.4.8) .                   `Error: [$parse:isecdom] Referencing DOM nodes in Angular expressions is disallowed! Expression: save($event.target.checked, shoe)`

Comment: The solution here was to pass `$event` as the first parameter into `save()` . Angular doesn't seem to like the deep reference of the node. So modified to `ng-click="save($event, shoe)"` then `console.log(isChecked)` from the controller, correctly logged the selected input(s). From there you can deep reference the 'checked' node. For example (within save function), `isChecked = isChecked.target.checked`.

Comment: @bruh  I have update the code snippet to avoid this error from happening.

Comment: Thanks! I gave we discovered that solution around the same time. I really appreciate all your help!

Answer (score 1):

You can get the checked items using a angular.Foreach it becomes easy when you have multiple items checked.

```
$scope.checkedItems = [];
        angular.forEach($scope.shoebox, function(value, key) {
          if (value.selected)
            $scope.checkedItems.push(value.name);
});
```

**Demo**

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.shoebox = [{
    name: 'Reboke',
    selected: false
  }, {
    name: 'woodlands',
    selected: false
  }, {
    name: 'Nike',
    selected: false
  }, {
    name: 'Fila',
    selected: false
  }];
  $scope.checkedItems = function() {
    $scope.checkedItems = [];
    angular.forEach($scope.shoebox, function(value, key) {
      if (value.selected)
        $scope.checkedItems.push(value.name);
    });

  }
});
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>AngularJS </title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.7/angular.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <ul>
  <li ng-repeat='shoe in shoebox'>
    <input type='checkbox' ng-model='shoe.selected' id='shoe-{{shoe.name}}'>
    <label for='shoe-{{shoe.name}}'>{{shoe.name}}</label>
  </li>
  <button ng-click='checkedItems()'>Apply</button>
   Checked items are: {{checkedItems}}
</ul>
     
</body>
</html>
```